# Run time error 1004 - MS Office excel can not create or use the data range because it is too complex

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code for filtering data with particular criteria and selecting filtered data, copy and pasting visible cells only in different sheet. However, I am getting error "Run time error 1004" stating MS Office excel can not create or use the data range because it is too complex.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8H0J.jpg)

below is the code that I am using

```
Set mwb = ActiveWorkbook
fname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
pth = path
period = Sheets("DEF").Range("F18").Value
ddate = Range("L6").Value


Sheets("MacroTOSplit").Select
blr = Range("C50").End(xlUp).Row
Rcfield = Range("C1").Value
For a = 4 To blr Step 1
    Sheets("MacroTOSplit").Select
    If Cells(a, "C").Value <> "" Then
       rc1 = Cells(a, "C").Value

        Sheets("XYZ").Select
        Cells.AutoFilter
        If lr >= 2 Then
        Range("B2:B" & lr + 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If



       Sheets("ABC").Select


       dlr = lr
       Set datarange = Sheets("ABC").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(dlr, "BG"))
       'Filter for each unit and copy the data
       datarange.AutoFilter Field:=Rcfield, Criteria1:=rc1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
       datarange.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(dlr, "BG")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("XYZ").Range("A2")
```

I am getting error at last step.

Please provide some solution for this.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: On this line `Range("B2:B" & lr + 1).EntireRow.Delete` and also this `If lr >= 2 Then` the `lr` variable is not set, so it actually does nothing. You can delete from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the last line to say:

```
datarange.Range(Cells(2, 1).address & ":" &  Cells(dlr, "BG").address)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, unfortunately it did not work. I still get same error.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are out of luck if you get the range too complex message.

However, if it is possible, you could pre-sort your data so that the selection is in fewer non-contiguous blocks.  This would make the selection less complex.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Will try doing that